# Why is the float value changing in my C program?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, floating-accuracy

In this program, the float array purchases[2] value is 90.50 but when I run the code it changes from 90.50 to 90.5010.990000. Why? purchases[0] and purchases[1] print fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float purchases[3] = {10.99, 14.25, 90.50};
    float total = 0;
    int k;

    //Total the purchases
    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f", purchases[0], purchases[1], purchases[2]); // Just so I know whats going on

    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        total += purchases[k];
        printf("%f\n", total); // Just so I know whats going on
        printf("%d\n", k);  // Just so I know whats going on
    }

    printf("Purchases total is %6.2f\n", total);
}
```

Comment: `"%.2f %.2f %.2f"` - There's no new line here

Comment: @P__J__: The complaint in this question is about “90.5010.990000”, which is caused by a missing new-line character in a `printf` and has nothing to do with floating-point arithmetic. Please do not mark questions as a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) simply because they contain floating-point somewhere within them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you print the contents of the `purchases` array, you don't print a newline.  So when you print `total` for the first time in the loop it appears on the same line.

Add the newline:

```
printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", purchases[0], purchases[1], purchases[2]);
```

Output:

```
10.99 14.25 90.50
10.990000
0
25.240000
1
115.739998
2
Purchases total is 115.74
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

> 90.5010.990000

is 90.50, and then, 10.990000. You forgot to use a newline.

Change this:

```
printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f", ..
```

to this:

```
printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f/n", ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @StoryTeller. No new line! School boy error right.

Should be:

```
printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", purchases[0], purchases[1], purchases[2]);
```

Sorry to bother you all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float purchases[3] = {10.99, 14.25, 90.50};
    float total = 0;
    int k;

    //Total the purchases
    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", purchases[0], purchases[1], purchases[2]); // Just so I know whats going on

    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        total += purchases[k];
        printf("%f\n", total); // Just so I know whats going on
        printf("%d\n", k);  // Just so I know whats going on
    }

    printf("Purchases total is %6.2f\n", total);
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you must take the time to explain each and every character to the [duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Just read about the Rubber Duck. Will tell the duck next time. Must be more vigilant.

Comment: @StoryTeller Too bad QuackOverflow was only an April Fool's joke. :(

Comment: LOL. I'd probably need to use that site more than this one!